# How take coordinates from Vector in maple

Tags: maple

Is any way to get coordinates from Vector in maple? For example if I would like have function `f(V) = sin(V[0]) + cos(V[1]) + V[2]`
Where V = (x,y,z). Is it possible in maple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Maple a Vector starts its indexing from 1 (not from 0). So the first entry is V[1], rather than V[0].

Also, a Vector can be constructed with either the `Vector` command or its angle-bracket shortcut notation. Round brackets do not construct a Vector, as they are delimiters for either grouping or arguments of function application.

```
restart:

f := V -> sin(V[1]) + cos(V[2]) + V[3]:

W := Vector([a,b,c]):

f(W);
                         sin(a) + cos(b) + c

Y := <3,7,11>:

f(Y);
                        sin(3) + cos(7) + 11
```

An Array is more flexible and can be constructed so as to start its indexing from 0.

```
g := V -> sin(V[0]) + cos(V[1]) + V[2]:

W := Array(0..2,[q,r,s]):

g(W);
                         sin(q) + cos(r) + s
```

Note that the LinearAlgebra package deals with Matrix and Vector. Also, some arithmetic operations (such as `.`) act in an elementwise manner for Array and not a way you might expect for doing computational linear algebra.

```
restart:

F := Array(1..3,[q,r,s]):

F . F;
                            [ 2   2   2]
                            [q , r , s ]

U := Vector[row]([q,r,s]):

U . U;
                           _     _     _  
                           q q + r r + s s
```

Note the complex conjugation occuring in the last example. And in contrast with Matrix structures, 2-dimensional Arrays are also multiplied elementwise under the `.` operator.